# VB.net incremented number concatenate with texbox value

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm learning vb.net. I'm trying to create an incremental number that starts at 00000 and concatenate that number with a value from a textbox (eg. JH00001), then insert it into the database.

Please can someone kindly help me with this as I'm totaly new to vb.net.

Thank you all for your assistance in advance. And I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `D5` precision specifier to indicate that the number should be at least 5 digits including leading zeros:

```
Dim valueFromTextBox As String = "JH"
Dim value As String = ""

For i = 0 To 99

  value = valueFromTextBox & i.ToString("D5")

 'Insert value to database

Next
```

Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more formatting methods

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim number as Integer = 1
Dim text as String = textbox1.text &= number.toString().padLeft(5, "0"c)
```

Answer (score 0):

A for loop should be what you need:

Something like:

```
Dim text As String = textbox1.text
Dim DBtext As String
For value As Integer = 0 To 5
    DBtext = text & value.ToString()
    'Insert anything else you need to do. Such as insert into DB.
Next
```

Just replace the 5 with however many times you need it to run.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using `String.Format` ...

```
For i = 0 to 1e6-1
    Dim FormattedString = String.Format("{0}{1:00000}", Textbox1.Text, i)
Next
```